# Redirect root View to a view in a different folder (Area folder) not in Root

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to redirect the login/registration page which is located under

> ~Views/Home/Index.chtml

The code checks to see if the user is already logged in, and if so, redirects to another page

> ~Areas/Feed/Views/Feed/Feed.cshtml

Here is what i have so far:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Helpers.UserInfoHelper.IsLoggedIn())
            {
                PersistData(Page.Feed);
                return View("../Areas/Feed/Views/Feed/Feed.chtml",  Helpers.UserInfoHelper.GetCachedUserInfo().UserName);
            }
            else
                return View("../Home/Index");
        }
```

I've been fiddling around with the paths but can't figure this one out. Any suggestions? Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { area = "areaName" });
```

if you are trying to go to the root pass "" for the area

Comment: Ahhhhh, I"m an idiot!! And here I was thinking i needed to rearrange my folders! Thanks, this worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use more than one `"../"` for instance: `"../../../Areas/Feed/Views/Feed/Feed.chtml"`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to include the Area folder or the View folder in your path. Remember, the routing engine will route it to /AreaName/Controller/ActionName

You don't need to tell it that you want a particular .cshtml file